# WPF Data Navigation Controls

Tags: wpf, navigation

I need to have a navigation set of controls to move through data (First, Next, Prev, Last, and specific record).  Is there any set of controls out there that have this wired up?  I am new to WPF and was hopeful something already exists that provides this capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need create them for yourself.
It will depends on your data model of course.

The WPF way to do it is binding your data to a ListView (or any ListItem container) and then use

```
myList.Items.MoveCurrentToFirst()
myList.Items.MoveCurrentToLast()
//etc....
```